# c: return all the filenames in directory

Tags: c, file

How to writte a function that is to return all the file names in a directory including files in the sub directories.
So far, I have something like this, but it doesn't work right, I try call this function and print out each element, it only prints the first element.

Can anyone tell me what I do wrong or the other approach of writing this function?

```
char **allFiles(char *dir, OPTIONS opts) {
        char **allfiles = malloc(sizeof(char **));
        struct dirent *dp;

        while((dp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {

            if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;
            if (dp->d_type == DT_DIR)
                allfiles = allFiles(strcat(strcat(dir, "/"), dp->d_name));

            if (dp->d_type != DT_DIR)
                *allfiles = strdup(strcat(strcat(strdup(dir), "/"), dp->d_name));

            ++allfiles;
        }
    closedir(dirp);
    return allfiles;
}
```

Comment: Again the standard question - what do you mean by "doesn't work right"?

Comment: Maybe this task would be completed easier using ftw() or nftw() calls.

Answer (score 2):

The allfiles[] array is filled by both the parent and the recursive child. The child inserts into it, but the results are overwitten by the parent.

UPDATE: after rereading, I see the array management looks Ok (besides possibly overrunning it's end)
Maybe you run out of file descriptors ?

UPDATE2: replace

```
if (dp->d_type != DT_DIR)
        *allfiles = strdup(strcat(strcat(strdup(dir), "/"), dp->d_name));
        ++allfiles;
```

By:

```
if (dp->d_type != DT_DIR)
        *allfiles++ = strdup(strcat(strcat(strdup(dir), "/"), dp->d_name));
```

Comment: I misread. I expected the alfiles[] array to be passed to the recursive all. There is more than one error in the fragment...

Comment: See Michel's reaction. Your array has only one element. You can increment the pointer, but it will point beyond your array. Also: the return from the recursive call overwrites the parent's pointer, and makes the parent's 1-element array inaccessable.

Comment: I'd say that reassignment of allfiles looks even more offensive.

Comment: one element is because your pointer points to the end of the array by the time you return it.

Comment: There are too many errors in the fragment to fully analyse it. I hadn't even seen the "strdup(strcat(strcat(strdup(dir), "/"), dp->d_name));" monstrum, though I silently copy-pasted it. Sigh, coffee.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: I thought because I increment the allfiles pointer, allfiles = allFiles(strcat(strcat(dir, "/"), dp->d_name)), will continue to append the next filename

Comment: @wildplasser: pls tell me others way that I can get the filename including its path, strdup(strcat(strcat(strdup(dir), "/"), dp->d_name)); I don't like it either

Comment: Xiaofan, you should consider trying to interpret your code step by step in your mind to realize what's going on.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: I see how the reassignment of the allfiles is wrong, but I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Xiaofan, it's not trivial. You'd have reallocate, because you don't know the size ahead of time, then append the data, etc., etc. It's simple, there is no magic, but not trivial, so I'll have to work.

Comment: I did try realloc in the while loop, when it runs, it gives an error, malloc: *** error for object 0x100800968: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6

Comment: The pointer array needs to be resized by both parent and child. Best is to use a struct containing {array,allocated size, number of elements used sofar} The strcat/strdup monstrum could be tackled by allocating strlen(dir) + strlen(entry) + 2 bytes, and strcpy/memcpy at the right places.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [glob()](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/glob/) if your platform has it?

Comment: how do I change the current directory to the subdirecotires if use glob()?

Comment: Oops, I didn't actually read your code and therefore didn't notice you wanted to recurse into subdirs. The problem there is that you reassign and increase allfiles which is not going to produce sensible results.

Comment: Same here. Point is: the code closely resembles something that would actually work, though it is terribly wrong in more than one spot.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the `allfiles` pointer cannot be done because you only allocated room to hold 1 pointer (to a `char *`). Another issue is that `allfiles` is overwritten when a directory is found (thus loosing all the previous found files and directories).